# How to handle null values when doing Collections.sort() with nested objects?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, null

**What is the best way to deal with `null` values, when doing `Collections.sort()` on nested objects?**

I'd like to sort a couple of objects, basically applying this rule:

```
@Override
public int compare(final InvoicePos invoicePosOne, final InvoicePos invoicePosTwo) {
   return invoicePosOne.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo().compareTo(invoicePosTwo.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo());
}
```

However, any of these objects can be `null` (i.e. invoice position, invoice and invoice number).

```
public class InvoicePos {
  private Invoice invoice = null;

  // ...
}

public class Invoice {
  private String invoiceNo = "";

  // ...
}
```

Do I have do do explicit `null`-checks on all my objects or is there an approach with less writing?

---

For clarification: I'm aware that my above example may raise NullPointerExceptions. Currently I'm doing the following and basically, I questioned myself, if there is any smarter approach.

```
     Collections.sort(allInvoicePositions, new Comparator<InvoicePos>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final InvoicePos invoicePosOne, final InvoicePos invoicePosTwo) {
           if (null == invoicePosOne && null == invoicePosTwo) {
              return 0;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosOne) {
              return -1;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosTwo) {
              return 1;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosOne.getInvoice() && null == invoicePosTwo.getInvoice()) {
              return 0;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosOne.getInvoice()) {
              return -1;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosTwo.getInvoice()) {
              return 1;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosOne.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo() && null == invoicePosTwo.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo()) {
              return 0;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosOne.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo()) {
              return -1;
           }

           if (null == invoicePosTwo.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo()) {
              return 1;
           }

           return invoicePosOne.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo().compareTo(invoicePosTwo.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo());
        }
     });
```

Comment: Well, don't allow `null` values to be inserted in your collection. Also, do `null` check in your comparator if you know that some fields may be `null`, otherwise make sure you don't have `null` values at all.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will end up with a NPE in `invoicePosOne.getInvoice().getInvoiceNo()` -->(`getInvoice()` returns an instance of `Invoice` right?. So, if it returns `null` , then you will have an NPE)

Comment: The problem you have is that the sort order needs to be consistent. i.e. if you decide that a < b it must also be true that b > a.  You have to chose whether null < x or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called as **NullComparator** in org.apache.commons.collections.jar.

This might help you https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/NullComparator.html.

Comment: Though, I'm not using Apache commons, I like the idea of ``NullComparator``. I had a closer look at [this article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jakarta-commons-cookbook/059600706X/ch04s06.html) and I think this could come in handy (if I was using Apache commons).

Comment: Yes, you don't have to write explicit null checks, as everything is handled already.

Comment: However, it won't handle the nested objects automatically. But still handy. And there is no need to include the entire Apache commons lib, its sufficient to implement your own ``NullComparator`` and ``ComparableComparator`` class. The code of Apache commons is available online.

Comment: Downvoter, can you put comments for improving my answer

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have do do explicit `null`-checks on all my objects or is there an approach with less writing?

If these values don't represent anything in your collection, then the best thing you can do is avoid them; don't allow inserting them, so you won't have to handle them when comparing items.

If you insist to have them, then you *must* check if they're `null` to avoid [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: I'm aware of the NPEs, just looking for a smart way to do all those checks.

Comment: @user1438038 consider using a map or encapsulate your data structure to have less comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have null values then you need to handle them explicitly and in a consistent way so to have a valid ordering relation. That is, something like:

```
compare (a, b) {
  if (a == null && b == null) return 0;      
  if (a == null) return -1;
  if (b == null) return +1;
  return comp(a,b);
}
```

Don't be tempted to do something like:

```
compare (a, b) {
  if (a == null || b == null) return -1;
  return comp(a,b);
}
```

which would break the ordering relation.